# Program works in Eclipse debugger but not anywhere else...?

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, debugging, thread-safety

The following code segment:

```
private class ConnectionControl implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        while( true )
        {
            if( !cnnct.isInMsgEmpty() )
                System.out.println( "Incoming message: " + cnnct.getInMsg().getPayloadString() ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Works when I run it in eclipse debugger and place a breakpoint at the System.out line.  However, if I run it normally I don't get the "Incoming message..." output.

Any thoughts on why this would be or how even to debug it???

---

Ahh figured it out... had a deadlock situation going on where two threads were using the same resource.  Thanks for your help guys!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to invoke Java code, depending on where you need it.

What you have shown is not enough to be self-standing, and should cause an error if you try to invoke it as an applet or a java application (java .... ConnectionControl).    It may be that Eclipse can invoke a Runnable - I have not seen it though.

Try

1. making the class public
2. add a static main method making it a Java application
3. put a message in the start of the main method so you can see it is invoked

Answer (score 0):

You're already using System.out.println for your program output. Add some sysouts that output where you are in the code and the status of various variables.

I don't know how this is being called but from the code I see your if condition is always evaluating false.